# Diff between WCF Service Application Template and Workflow Service Application Template in VS

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2012

What's the difference between the WCF Service Application Template and WCF Workflow Service Application Template in Visual Studio?. WCF Service is used to create a web service. What are the typical use of **WCF Workflow Service Application**?